# Why does my Outlook BCC myself on all outgoing emails?

Tags: ms-office

I have Outlook, and use the same @outlook.com, on my Windows laptop and iPhone.

On my Windows laptop, when I email, Outlook doesn't BCC myself. Good!

Yet when I send emails on iPhone, Outlook BCCs myself. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See settings > mail > always bcc myself.

[image]